# Bot creating unlimited tickets

Tags: discord.py

In this code tickets limit 1 but bot creating unlimited tickets

````py
ticket = utils.get(interaction.guild.text_channels, name = f"ticket-for-{interaction.user.name.lower().replace(' ', '-')}-{interaction.user.discriminator}")

        if ticket is not None: await interaction.response.send_message(f"You already have a ticket open at {ticket.mention}!", ephemeral = True)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `interaction` is a `Button` instance, and as such your `button` will be an `Interaction` instance, which should be a hint that the parameters of your callback are the wrong way around.

Consider looking at the official examples: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/views

Comment: See my post now

Comment: @PRINCE that is a completely different question. You can't just update your post to something unrelated when the issue is solved.

Comment: No  i did  mistake sorry